# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.sensors::Geolocation is not defined

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have a browser application and i want to use the Geolocation class. The problem is that i get that error when i try to use `Geolocation.isSupported`. I have imported the `flash.sensors.Geolocation` in the file but still get this error.

Any ideas? Thank you

later edit:

i got that error after i tried something like this:

```
public static function get isGeolocationSupported():Boolean
        {
            return Geolocation.isSupported;
        }
```

and called this function.

but if i call directly Geolocation.isSupported i get this error:

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.sensors::Geolocation could not
>   be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is supported only on mobile devices. It is not supported on desktop or AIR for TV devices neither on web applications.

Answer (score 0):

If you are receiving this error when publishing your flash as3 swf it is because you need to declare your class as public. Private classes can not be used as document classes because they are out of the class package and therefore are not a part of the private scope.

Answer (score 0):

The following error is due to not instantiating the Geolocation class
EX: geo = new Geolocation();

> ReferenceError: Error #1065: Variable flash.sensors::Geolocation is
>   not defined

The other error

> VerifyError: Error #1014: Class flash.sensors::Geolocation could not
>   be found.

Is because you did not import the class

Comment: i did both things but still got those errors, i think is because this class is not working for browser applications

Comment: I don't think so that would be another error. Currently you are getting import and null errors. Please post your full class code for the class that contains the isGeolocationSupported function

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

```
return (Geolocation != null);
```

But it gave me the same error - you will need to do a try/catch, unfortunately in this situation.

```
var result:Boolean = false;
try
{
    result = Geolocation.isSupported;
}
    catch (e:Error)
{
    trace(e.message);
}
finally
{
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer come too late, but I was receiving same error yesterday and I could arrange it. You can test the app in Adobe Device Central, where you can change the device you are using. Actually it doesn't work in the default device. I have had also problems when trying to use the app in my smartphone through a swf player, because of the flash version. I had to change it to 10.1 or lower versions (versions supporting Geolocation), and anyway I haven't been able to make it work well, though it was running ok on Device Central.